# How to set width of an element in %

Tags: html, css

I need to know is how can I set the width of an element in `%`.Please provide some information about the ratio of setting width in percentage.

Suppose I have a following html

```
     <dl  >
         <dd >
         <dl>
        <dt >
    something
        </dt>
        <dd>
      something
        </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
        <dt  >

     something
        </dt>
        <dd >
     something
        </dd>
         </dl>
         <dl >             
        <dt >
    something
        </dt>
        <dd>
    something
        </dd>
        </dl>
        </dd>
       </dl>
```

I need to know How can set the width of each element using %.Is der any relation for setting the height in the css?
Thanks in advance

Comment: % of what? What's wrong with `dd { width: 50%; }`?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? just setting the width is easy: width:10%;

Comment: @deceze. Pls help me how to find the composition ie 350px=20% only example.I know that i need to specify width:10% but I need to know how I will make sure  about the 20%.Whether I need to check always in browser,at wat ratio it is suits best?

Comment: I think you want inline elements with no word-wrap that stay on one line. As far as I understand you don't know what percentage to use because the width of the content is variable? Try  display:inline-block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a width via % works just the same as setting with pixels.

```
width: 35%;
```

instead of

```
width: 250px;
```

There ARE ratios that people tend to use with wireframes that are pretty standard. YUI2 dealt quite a bit with this.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/